# Binding A Single Control to a View Model Property

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I'm attempting to bind the text of a TextBlock control as shown:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="ProgressViewModel" Text="{Binding FileName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

"ProgressViewModel" is a class that exists in my project and exposes the FileName property:

```
    private string _fileName;
    public string FileName
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
        set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _fileName, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }
```

I know that FileName is being updated correctly as I can watch its value in the debuggger. However, I can't get the XAML binding to work. I'm trying to avoid setting a master binding in the Window.Resources as some articles have suggested since I have multiple view models in this project.

Full view model:

```
using MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MaterialDesignTest

{
    public class ProgressViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer progressTimer;

    private double _saveProgressButton;
    public double SaveProgressButton
    {
        get { return _saveProgressButton; }
        set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _saveProgressButton, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }
    private string _fileName;
    public string FileName
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
        set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _fileName, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    private bool _isSaveComplete;
    public bool IsSaveComplete
    {
        get { return _isSaveComplete; }
        private set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _isSaveComplete, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    private bool _isSaving;
    public bool IsSaving
    {
        get { return _isSaving; }
        private set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _isSaving, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    int progress = 0;
    int cycles = 0;
    public ProgressViewModel()
    {

    }
    public void KickOffProgressTimer()
    {
        progressTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        progressTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(progressTimerTick);
        progressTimer.Interval = 40;
        progressTimer.Start();
    }

    private async void progressTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileName = SelectRandomString();

        if (progress < 100 && cycles < 2)
        {
            if (progress == 99)
            {
                cycles++;
                progress = 0;
            }

            IsSaveComplete = false;
            IsSaving = true;
            progress++;
            SaveProgressButton = progress;
        }
        else
        {
            IsSaveComplete = true;
            IsSaving = false;
            progressTimer.Enabled = false;
            SaveProgressButton = 0;

            await NonBlockingDelay(1750);

            DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand.Execute(null, null);
        }
    }
    async Task NonBlockingDelay(int value)
    {
        await Task.Delay(value);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> RaisePropertyChanged()
    {
        return args => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    static string SelectRandomString()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var questions = new List<string>{
            @"C:\Files\Filename1",
            @"C:\Filename2",
            @"C:\Filename3",
            @"C:\Filename4",
            @"C:\Temp\Files\Filename5",
            @"C:\Filename6",
            @"C:\Demo\LongFolderName\Filename7",
            @"C:\Filename8",
            @"C:\Filename9",
        };
        int index = random.Next(questions.Count);
        return(questions[index]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Look at the output window, there should be some binding error message printed.

Comment: That's good to know about. I do see the following:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'FileName' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=1452031459)'. BindingExpression:Path=FileName; DataItem='String' (HashCode=1452031459); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: Try Text=“{Binding ProgressViewModel.FileName}”, don’t need to set the DataContext for this single control.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you're currently binding to string value `"ProgressViewModel"`; instead, you should bind to an instance to an object of type `ProgressViewModel`. Try:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.DataContext>
        <ns:ProgressViewModel />
    </TextBlock.DataContext>
</TextBlock>
```

*Here, I assume you defined the namespace that contains `ProgressViewModel` as an XML namespace `ns` in the root tag. I also assume that `ProgressViewModel` has a public parameterless constructor.*

The following is how you define `ns`. If `ProgressViewModel` is defined in namespace `WpfApp1`, `ns` should be written like this: `xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"`

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class ProgressViewModel
    {
    //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added `xmlns:ns="ProgressViewModel"` to the Window properties, and ProgressViewModel is declared as `public class ProgressViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`. <br/> However, I'm getting this error in XAML: The name "ProgressViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "ProgressViewModel".

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected the namespace definition and am no longer receiving errors, however the binding continues to render a blank value.

Comment: @user3342256, That's because your `FileName` property is returning an empty (or null) string value.

Comment: Hmm. Hovering over `<TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"` during debugging shows the value correctly bound. Not sure why it isn't rendering in the UI.

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="File.txt" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>` works. Replacing that with your binding example yields nothing in the UI, but I can see the value bound to the property while hovering over the property in XAML. I have the property hard-coded to a string in the view model for testing.

Comment: @user3342256, Make sure `RaisePropertyChanged();` is actually raising `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event in your view-model. Since you claim the value is actually present during debug, but not showing in UI, that means that either your view-model is not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` or the event I mentioned above was never raised with appropriate parameters.

Comment: I've added the full view model to my question. I set a breakpoint on `private Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> RaisePropertyChanged()` and it is being entered whenever a value is updated.

Comment: I should note that other properties referenced in the same view model, such as IsSaveComplete, are being raised successfully and reflect in the UI.

Comment: @user3342256, `RaisePropertyChanged();` is not even raising the event; instead, it's encapsulating a method that raises the event; however, even if this method was being called anywhere in `MutateVerbose`, it won't be aware of the property being changed, thus, nothing will be affected. To fix: add property name as a parameter in `RaisePropertyChanged`, and use that parameter in the method you encapsulate to invoke the event.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I follow your suggestion to fix. Can you provide an example please? `RaisePropertyChanged` does not accept arguments.